# Is there a function that lets you view the details of an rds file?

Tags: r, model

I am using an R package that saves a model as an rds file. Is there a function in R to see the details of the saved model?

Comment: Not without reading it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS files are generic object containers. You can store anything in them: data, models, functions, etc. They are unaware of what's inside until you actually load it up. So there would be no way to extract specific model parameters from the RDS file until you call `readRDS` to load it into your R workspace.

And depending on the modeling function you use, you may not necessarily be able to recover the exact parameters used to generate the model. Not all function save everything in the output.